# Cron not logrotating for cron.daily

Tags: cron, logrotate, rhel7

I'm running a [rhel7](/questions/tagged/rhel7) server and I have a rsyslog logrotate config file that doesn't seem to run using cron job. It will only work if i run it manually

Troubleshooting steps i took:

```
logrotate -df /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Result: Able to log rotate successfully

```
run-parts /etc/cron.daily
```

Result: Able to log rotate successfully (Verify by looking at timestamp of cron log in `/var/log/cron`)

```
Jun  6 15:42:19 server run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[144143]: starting logrotate
Jun  6 15:49:26 server run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[146078]: finished logrotate
```

However, the problem is if i let it run normally by itself it does not seem to rotate.This is the log of the cron job that ran:

```
Jun  6 03:19:01 server run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[43048]: starting logrotate
Jun  6 03:19:01 server run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[43069]: finished logrotate
```

The permission for logrotate in `/etc/cron.daily/` is already 755

Regarding SELINUX permissioning of the log files in question,  have already set them correctly using

```
chcon --reference /var/log /directory/files
```

Any ideas?